# After moving data from my old Mac to a new one, how can I change the name of my macOS computer so it uses its current name and not its former name?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

I just transitioned my data from a Mac mini to a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina.

I renamed the user for the new MacBook Pro, but when I downloaded the VNC server, it keeps saying the MacBook Pro’s name is what the prior Mac mini was, instead of the MacBook Pro.

And if I try to connect with the Mac mini from my new MacBook Pro, it won’t go to it because it thinks I am looking for the MacBook Pro I am on.

I can't seem to purge the name of the Mac mini from the MacBook Pro in the VNC server or viewer App.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure your `ComputerName`, `HostName` and `LocalHostName` are all the same on your MacBook Pro.

Pretty sure this issue happened because while you cloned the data from your Mac mini to the MacBook Pro, it retained the ComputerName, HostName and LocalHostName of the old Mac mini. Of course your MacBook Pro perhaps has one of those items correctly set to the new MacBook Pro value, but all should be the same.

You can check the values of `ComputerName`, `HostName` and `LocalHostName` using `scutil --get` like this:

```
scutil --get ComputerName
scutil --get HostName
scutil --get LocalHostName
```

And you can set those values using `scutil --set` like this:

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName 'yourHostName'
sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName 'yourHostName'
```